# PostgreSQL rank only continuous rows on ordered data

Tags: postgresql, rank, dense-rank

So I ran into this interesting problem, which at first seems easy at first with a simple sql window function.
But it isn't. Any solutions that use only rank, or dense rank?

Basically I want to assign rank based on petrol price and effective from dates. The table structure and its data is as below.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/se6mB.png]

Comment: Edit your post and write your data as text.

Answer (score 2):

If you are expecting an output like this

```
price dte        rn 
----- ---------- -- 
65.5  2013-06-01 1  
66.3  2014-06-01 1  
66.3  2015-12-01 2  
67    2012-01-01 1  
67    2012-06-01 2  
67    2013-01-01 3  
67    2014-01-01 4  
67    2016-01-01 5
```

the query should be

```
select *
      ,row_number() over(partition by price order by dte) rn
from price;
```

OR

```
SELECT *
       ,rank() OVER (PARTITION BY price ORDER BY dte) rn
FROM price;
```

---

PostgreSQL's [Window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/tutorial-window.html)